# How do I map over a contacts array to produce a new array with objects and properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am looking to map over an array to create a new array with relevant properties pulled out. I have successfully accessed my contacts on my phone and want to push the data into a more organized structure. How do I map over Array In to get to Array Out using the first values for email and phone numbers if they are present? Below is an example of a contacts array:

**Array In**

```
let arrayIn=  [
    {phoneNumbers:[
        { label: 'work',  number: '+3476859087'},
        { label: 'mobile', number: '+4567893214'}
        ],
        lookupKey:"12345",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"John",contactType:"person",name:"John Smith",id:"879",
        emails:[
            {email:'johnSmith@gmail.com'}
        ],
        lastName:"Smith",
    },
    {phoneNumbers:[
        { label: 'mobile', number: '+3476859087'},
        { label: 'work', number: '+4567773214'}
        ],
        lookupKey:"890744",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"Carl",name:"Carl Johnson",id:"879",
        emails:[
            {email:'cjohnsonh@gmail.com'}
        ],
        lastName:"johnson",
    }
    ]
```

I would like to end up with the following:
**Array out**

```
[
      {name: 'John Smith', phone: 3476859087, email: 'jsmith@gmail.com'},
      {name: 'Carl Johnson', phone: 3476859087, email: 'cJohnson@gmail.com'}
    ]
```

I've mapped over the array to create a contact list and as I select each one I want to push it into the state. My snack is here for reference: https://snack.expo.io/@fauslyfox110/testingreferrals

Not looking for anyone to do my snack for me, just to help me with the array portion to go from array In to array out.

**Answer that worked**

```
let arrayOut = arrayIn.reduce((acc, {name, phoneNumbers, emails}) => {
  return [...acc, {
    'name': name,
    'phone': phoneNumbers[0]['number'].replace('+', ''),
    'email': emails[0].email
  }];
}, []);

console.log(arrayOut);
```

Comment: what is your specific problem with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some Sytax errors in your data, mainly that you were using `[]` and then assigning *key:value* pairs, which would belong in an object - I've swapped the `[]` for `{}` in this case

I've used a [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate through your data and return the desired Array. I wasn't sure how you wanted the phone number handled, so I'm returning just the first one

```js
const arrayIn = [{
    phoneNumbers: [{
      label: 'work',
      number: '+3476859087'
    }, {
      label: 'mobile',
      number: '+4567893214'
    }],
    lookupKey: "12345",
    company: "PHONE",
    firstName: "John",
    contactType: "person",
    name: "John Smith",
    id: "879",
    emails: [{
      email: 'johnSmith@gmail.com'
    }],
    lastName: "Smith",
  },
  {
    phoneNumbers: [{
      label: 'mobile',
      number: '+3476859087'
    }, {
      label: 'work',
      number: '+4567773214'
    }],
    lookupKey: "890744",
    company: "PHONE",
    firstName: "Carl",
    name: "Carl Johnson",
    id: "879",
    emails: [{
      email: 'cjohnsonh@gmail.com'
    }],
    lastName: "johnson",
  }
]

let arrayOut = arrayIn.reduce((acc, {
  name,
  phoneNumbers,
  emails
}) => {
  return [...acc, {
    'name': name,
    'phone': phoneNumbers[0]['number'].replace('+', ''),
    'email': emails[0].email
  }];
}, []);

console.log(arrayOut);
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake when posting the question, the array has nested arrays not objects with [] vs {}

Comment: Ahh I just updated the array, but ur answer should work with just referencing number instead of zero. I will check rn

Answer (score 0):

Does this clarify?

```js
let inputArray = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}]

let outputArray = inputArray.map(inputArrayItem => { return  {name: inputArrayItem.name}; });

console.log(outputArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Array In has some syntax errors in it.  I didn't do a map but I did it in a for loop instead, but it looks something like this.

```js
let arrayIn =   [
    {phoneNumbers:[
        '+3476859087',
        '+4567893214'
        ],
        lookupKey:"12345",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"John",contactType:"person",name:"John Smith",id:"879",
        emails:[
            'johnSmith@gmail.com'
        ],
        lastName:"Smith",
    },
    {phoneNumbers:[
        '+3476859087',
        '+4567773214'
        ],
        lookupKey:"890744",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"Carl",name:"Carl Johnson",id:"879",
        emails:[
            'cjohnsonh@gmail.com'
        ],
        lastName:"johnson",
    }
   ]

 let arrayOut = []

 for(let i = 0; i < arrayIn.length; i++){
        let contact = {
        name: arrayIn[i].name,
      phone: arrayIn[i].phoneNumbers[0],
      email: arrayIn[i].emails[0],
    }
    arrayOut.push(contact);
 }

 console.log(arrayOut);
```

here is my jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/1brL2cz0/

I didn't split off the '+' from the phone numbers, but that you can easily do.